# Transfinite composition

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I am reading Chapter 10 of P.S.Hirschhorn book on model categories, and I have a question about Proposition 10.2.6. and 10.2.7.

Proposition 10.2.7. gives some sufficient conditions for a map  $f:P\to Q$ in a cocomplete category $\mathcal{C}$ with a class of maps $\mathcal{D}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ to be a transfinite composition of maps of $\mathcal{D}$.

I am not sure about the requirement that for every $\beta +1<\gamma$ the map
$$\text{colim}_{\alpha\le \beta} X_\alpha \to X_{\beta+1}$$ 
should be an element of $\mathcal{D}$, since the colimit on the right would be just $X_\beta$ and in the proof we will need also the map
$$\text{colim}_{\alpha<\beta}X_\alpha \to X_\beta$$
to be in $\mathcal{D}$, for all limit ordinal $\beta<\gamma$. I believe it is just a typo that should instead be read like: for every $\beta<\gamma$ the map
$$\text{colim}_{\alpha<\beta} X_\alpha \to X_{\beta}$$
is in $\mathcal{D}$. But I'd rather be sure I'm not missing something.

The second par of the question is about the proof of Proposition 10.2.7. In the proof he defines a functor $X:\lambda+1\to \mathcal{C}$, where $\lambda$ is the unique ordinal isomorphic to a given set $S$, after choosing a well order of $S$, by letting
$$X_\beta=\left(\coprod_{\alpha<\beta}D_\alpha\right) \amalg \left(\coprod_{\beta\le \alpha<\lambda+1}C_{\alpha}\right)$$

To apply Proposition 10.2.6. we would like to have $X_0 =\coprod_{s\in S}C_s$, which is true, but also $\text{colim}_{\alpha<\lambda+1}X_\alpha = \coprod_{s\in S}D_s$, which seems to be false, since
$$\text{colim}_{\alpha<\lambda+1}X_\alpha = \text{colim}_{\alpha\le\lambda}X_{\alpha} = X_\lambda = \left(\coprod_{\alpha<\lambda}D_{\alpha}\right)\amalg C_\lambda$$

Do you know how to fix this point?

Comment: I agree on the first part. For the second, notice that we don't have $C_\lambda$, as the elements of $S$ (after the identification $S=\lambda$) are precisely the ordinals $\beta < \lambda$, so that the sum of the $C_i$'s when $\alpha = \lambda$ is isomorphic to an initial object in $\mathcal C$.

Comment: @AndreaGagna thank you for your answer! Indeed you are right, I was mistaken.

Comment: Still, as you made me notice in private, the last pushout in the proof of proposition 10.2.7 is not the right one.